# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xml.serialize.OutputFormat

Tags: java, xml, webservice, soap, xhtml

estoy haciendo un programa web para consumo de servicios, ya tengo un servicio hecho y estoy haciendo una interfaz en XHTML, utilizo un Servlet para la lógica. El detalle es que al correr el proyecto me manda el error **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xml.serialize.OutputFormat**
Cabe mencionar que ya tengo la librería xerces.jar importada, tengo una clase de prueba con un main y ese si funciona, me saca los datos por consola pero al hacerlo en modo web tira ese error. Espero puedan ayudarme, ¡Saludos!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

--- Servlet ---

```
    package soaprequesttester;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.io.StringReader;
    import java.io.StringWriter;
    import java.io.Writer;

    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLConnection;

    import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
    import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

    import org.apache.xml.serialize.OutputFormat;
    import org.apache.xml.serialize.XMLSerializer;

    import org.w3c.dom.Document;

    import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
    import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

    public class SoapRequestServlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "text/html; charset=windows- 
   1252";
    private static final String DOC_TYPE = "<!DOCTYPE html  \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\"\n"
            + "\"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">";

    private String wsURL = "";
    private String requestMessage = "";

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Formatear la respuesta del mensaje SOAP o no
        String formatXML = request.getParameter("formatXML");
        // Obtener datos para SOAPAction
        String target = request.getParameter("target");
        String metodo = request.getParameter("metodo");

        // Obtener el endpoint
        if (!request.getParameter("wsdl").equals(""))
            wsURL = request.getParameter("wsdl");
        else
            throw new ServletException("Sin ubicaci[on de endpoint!");

        // Obtener el mensaje SOAP request
        String entradaXml = request.getParameter("soapmessage");
        requestMessage = entradaXml;

        // Solicitud de HTTP al web service
        URL url = new URL(wsURL);
        URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection httpConexion = (HttpURLConnection) conexion;
        String respuestaString = "";
        String salidaString = "";
        String SOAPAction = target + "/" + metodo; //"http://service.prueba.com/buscarPorId";

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        OutputStream salida = null;
        InputStreamReader isr = null;
        BufferedReader entrada = null;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[entradaXml.length()];
        buffer = entradaXml.getBytes();
        baos.write(buffer);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

        // Establecer par[ametros HTTP adecuados.
        httpConexion.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(b.length));
        httpConexion.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        httpConexion.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", SOAPAction);
        httpConexion.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpConexion.setDoOutput(true);
        httpConexion.setDoInput(true);
        salida = httpConexion.getOutputStream();

        // Escribe el contenido de la solicitud en salida HTTP
        salida.write(b);
        salida.close();

        // Lee la respuesta.
        isr = new InputStreamReader(httpConexion.getInputStream());
        entrada = new BufferedReader(isr);

        // Escribe la respuesta del mensaje SOAP a String.
        while ((respuestaString = entrada.readLine()) != null) {
            salidaString += respuestaString + (formatXML == null ? "\n" : "");
        }
        // Formatea el mensaje cuando el checkbox está habilitado.
        if (formatXML != null)
            salidaString = formatoXML(salidaString);

        // Escribe la respuesta XML.
        response.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE);
        PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
        printWriter.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>");
        printWriter.println(DOC_TYPE);
        printWriter.println("<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"en\" lang=\"en\">");
        printWriter.println("<head><title>Webservice tester</title></head>");
        printWriter.println("<body>");
        printWriter.println("<form action=\"soaprequestservlet\" method=\"post\">");
        printWriter.println("<label for=\"wsdl\">Webservice endpoint</label>");
        printWriter.println("<input type=\"text\" name=\"endpoint\" value=\"" + wsURL + "\" size=\"120\" id=\"wsdl\" style= \"; font-size: 12px; color: blue;\" />");
        printWriter.println("<label for=\"FormatXML\">Format XML</label>");
        printWriter.println("<input id=\"FormatXML\" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"formatXML\" value=\"formatXML\" checked=\"checked\"/>");
        printWriter.println("<p/><table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" border=\"0\">");
        printWriter.println("<tr>");
        printWriter.println("<td width=\"45%\">");
        printWriter.println("<h3>SOAP Message Request</h3>");
        printWriter.println("<textarea style= \"; font-size: 11px; color: blue\";  name=\"mensajesoap\" cols=\"80\" rows=\"40\" title=\"SOAP Message Request\" id=\"soaprequest\">" + requestMessage + "</textarea>");
        printWriter.println("</td>");
        printWriter.println("<td width=\"45%\">");
        printWriter.println("<h3>SOAP Message Response</h3>");
        printWriter.println("<textarea style= \"; font-size: 11px; color: blue\"; name=\"soapmessageresponse\" cols=\"80\" rows=\"40\"");
        printWriter.println("title=\"SOAP Message Response\" id=\"soapresponse\"");

        // Escribe el mensaje de respuesta SOAP en el textaresa.
        printWriter.println(salidaString);

        // Continua escribiendo el XHTML
        printWriter.println("</textarea>");
        printWriter.println("</td>");
        printWriter.println("</tr>");
        printWriter.println("</table>");
        printWriter.println("<input type=\"submit\" name=\"Test SOAP Request\" value=\"Test SOAP Request\"/>");
        printWriter.println("</form>");
        printWriter.println("</body></html>");
        printWriter.close();
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE);
        // Escribe el XHTML
        PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
        printWriter.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>");
        printWriter.println(DOC_TYPE);
        printWriter.println("<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"en\" lang=\"en\">");
        printWriter.println("<head><title>Webservice tester</title></head>");
        printWriter.println("<body >");
        printWriter.println("<form action=\"soaprequestservlet\" method=\"post\">");
        printWriter.println("<label for=\"wsdl\">Webservice endpoint</label>");
        printWriter.println("<input type=\"text\" name=\"endpoint\" value=\"\" size=\"120\" id=\"wsdl\" style= \"font-size: 12px; color: blue;\" />");
        printWriter.println("<label for=\"FormatXML\">Format XML</label>");
        printWriter.println("<input id=\"FormatXML\" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"formatXML\" value=\"formatXML\" checked=\"checked\"/>");
        printWriter.println("<p/><table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" border=\"0\">");
        printWriter.println("<tr>");
        printWriter.println("<td width=\"45%\">");
        printWriter.println("<h3>SOAP Message Request</h3>");
        printWriter.println("<textarea style= \" font-size: 11px; color: blue;\" name=\"mensajesoap\" cols=\"80\" rows=\"40\" title=\"SOAP MessageRequest\" id=\"soaprequest\"></textarea>");
        printWriter.println("</td>");
        printWriter.println("<td width=\"45%\">");
        printWriter.println("<h3>SOAP Message Response</h3>");
        printWriter.println("<textarea style= \"font-size: 11px; color: blue;\"  name=\"soapmessageresponse\" cols=\"80\" rows=\"40\"");
        printWriter.println("title=\"Soap Request\" id=\"soapresponse\"></textarea>");
        printWriter.println("</td>");
        printWriter.println("</tr>");
        printWriter.println("</table>");
        printWriter.println("<input type=\"submit\" name=\"Test SOAP Request\" value=\"Test SOAP Request\"/>");
        printWriter.println("</form>");
        printWriter.println("</body></html>");
        printWriter.close();
    }

    // formatea el XML en String

    public String formatoXML(String sinFormatoXml) {
        try {
            Document documento = parsearXml(sinFormatoXml);
            OutputFormat formato = new OutputFormat(documento);
            formato.setIndenting(true);
            formato.setIndent(3);
            Writer salida = new StringWriter();
            XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(salida, formato);
            serializer.serialize(documento);
            return salida.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private Document parsearXml(String entrada) {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(entrada));
            return db.parse(is);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

--- xml ---

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1252'?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SoapRequestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>soaprequesttester.SoapRequestServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SoapRequestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/soaprequestservlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

--- XHTML ---

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Webservice tester</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="soaprequestservlet" method="post">
        <label for="wsdl">Webservice endpoint</label> 
        <input type="text" name="wsdl" size="120" id="wsdl" style="font-size: 11px; color: blue;" />

        <label for="FormatXML">Formato XML</label> 
        <input id="FormatXML" type="checkbox" name="formatXML" value="formatXML" checked="checked" /><br/><br/>

        <label for="wsdl">Target</label> 
        <input type="text" name="target" size="60" id="target" style="font-size: 11px; color: blue;" />

        <label for="wsdl">Método</label> 
        <input type="text" name="metodo" size="60" id="metodo" style="font-size: 11px; color: blue;" /> 


        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="45%">
                    <h3>SOAP Request</h3> <textarea
                        style="font-size: 11px; color: blue;" name="soapmessage" cols="80"
                        rows="35" title="SOAP MessageRequest" id="soaprequest"></textarea>
                </td>

                <td width="45%">
                    <h3>SOAP Response</h3> <textarea
                        style="font-size: 11px; color: blue;" name="soapmessageresponse"
                        cols="80" rows="35" title="Soap Request" id="soapresponse"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="Test SOAP Request"
            value="Test SOAP Request" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ya lograste resolver el error?

Comment: Aún no, dice que no está la clase de la librería, pero ahí está :(

Comment: y para importar la librería usaste maven? porque al parecer esa versión no trae esa clase

Comment: No, es un Dynamic Web Project

Comment: Parece ser un caso en que importas la librería pero no la marcas para ser agregada al compilado por eso te funciona con un main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a la ayuda de Roberto le pude dar solución:
Primero tube que exportar el jar en "Libraries", despues marcarlo como dijo Roberto en "Order and exports" y ponerlo arriba, despues abrí la carpeta de Libraries e importé el .jar. Al terminar me mandó un error diferente; ahora era falta de otra clase -> org.wc3.dom.EntityTraversal, busqué la librería XML APIs » 1.4.01 hice el mismo procedimiento y solucionado. Espero les sirva ñ.ñ

Answer (score 0):

Parece ser un caso en que importas la librería pero no la marcas para ser agregada al compilado por eso te funciona con un main. Prueba esto, en `propiedades del proyecto > java build path > Order and Export` verifica que el jar tenga la casilla marcada, esto le hará que eclipse incluya el jar cuando despliegue el proyecto en el servidor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El jar que ves es solo de ejemplo, este caso sucede porque en un webproject puede suceder que la libreria la posea el servidor de aplicaciones ya sea porque esta por defecto o sean librerías externas que agregas, entonces debes especificar cuando importes un jar que sea exportado con el compilado.

Comment: Hola Roberto, gracias por responder, he hecho lo que me mencionas, efectivamente no estaba marcada la casilla; la he marcado pero me sigue mandando el mismo error :(